# Python 3: accessing windows share under Linux by UNC path

Tags: python, unc

First, lets ensure that windows share is accesable:

```
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/test
```

Let's try mount, but it's fail:

```
$ sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.10/work /mnt/test
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on //192.168.0.10/work,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
   need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

But if provide dummy user/pass (i.e. point exactly 'USERNAME' and 'PASSWD'), mount success:

```
$ sudo mount -t cifs -o username=USERNAME,password=PASSWD //192.168.0.10/work /mnt/test
$ ls /mnt/test/*.txt
/mnt/test/1.txt
$ umount test
```

Now lets try python:

```
$ python -V
Python 3.5.2+
$ python
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir(r'//192.168.0.10/work')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '//192.168.0.10/work'
```

I'm trying four slashes, backslashes, combine it, with or without `r`, unicode escaping (`bytes(path, "utf-8").decode("unicode_escape")`), all this fail with `No such file or directory`. May be reason of this fail is user/pass, but I have no imagine how add it to UNC.

ps. Also I try `pysmb` library, it's work fine without user/pass. But I dont want using additional lib if it possible.

Comment: Python won't 'automatically' mount the drive. After you have the windows share mounted in the shell, you can access it via os.listdir(r'/mnt/test').

Comment: I don't want "mount". I want only access via UNC. Mounting in my question only proof of share accesable.

Answer (score 1):

You must mount a UNC path on Linux.  The OS has no way of understanding two backslashes except when mounting the path.  So to make this automatic, just write some Python code to call the necessary Linux commands to accomplish the mount task and then refer to a file path as you normally would.

Example running Linux "ls" command from Python.

```
import os
os.system('ls')
```

Now follow one of these two methods.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18925/how-to-mount-a-device-in-linux

https://www.putorius.net/mount-windows-share-linux.html